# Comparing/Implementing `app.use(cors(corsOptions));` and `app.options('*', cors(corsOptions));` in Express/Node Application

Tags: node.js, express, cors

I am new to implementing CORS(enabling it for everyone) in a Node/Express application. I have found a snippet of code in `app.js` which is mentioned below:

```
const express = require('express');
const corsOptions = {
  origin: '*',
};
const app = express();
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.options('*', cors(corsOptions));
app.listen(config.PORT);
```

I found the last two lines of code to be redundant. I am not sure as I am unable to test the CORS right now due to limited knowledge/understanding and resources on running Node/Express project.

Is it sufficient if we mention either `app.use(cors(corsOptions));` or
`app.options('*', cors(corsOptions));`?
If Yes, is there a difference in their implementation?
If No, how does each line of code configure the Express Application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the `options()` will do the exact the same but only for the request path `*` and http `OPTIONS` requests.

The `use()` will not care about the verb of the request, but can have a request path as first argument if needed.

Comment: What does "http `OPTIONS` requests" mean? I think you mean corsOptions, don't you?

Comment: It is another type of request, such as GET, POST etc. To look if Cors is enabled for a service, a “pre-flight” request of type OPTIONS is usually sent. It expects some Cors headers back. But if you want all requests to be reachable from another domain, you should add it to all type of requests.